# KeyboardAvoidingView not working with react native bottom sheet

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bottom-sheet

I have a bottom sheet.
[image]

When user taps on input i want to move this sheet up, but I coudn't make it with keyboardAvoidingView.
code looks like this:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={'position'}>
<BottomSheetModal
    ref={bottomSheetRef}
    index={1}
    snapPoints={snapPoints}
    onChange={handleSheetChanges}
    backdropComponent={renderBackdrop}
    handleComponent={null}
    handleHeight={20}
    handleIndicatorStyle={{
      height: 0,
      width: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'red',
    }}
    style={styles.borderStyle}
    >
      
    <View style={{flex: 1, paddingVertical: 16, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
        <IconButton
          onPress={onCloseButtonPress}
          icon={'cross'}
          iconSize={23}
          iconColor={'#1A1A1A'}
          containerStyle={styles.closeButton}
        />

        <CreateCollectionModal
          renderSubmitButton={renderCreateCollectionButton}
          onSubmit={props.onCollectionCreate}
          {...props}
        />
    </View>
    
  </BottomSheetModal>
  </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Any idea about it?